# Convert from \Device\HarddiskVolume1 to C: in vb6

Tags: vb6

Is there any way to convert from `\Device\HarddiskVolume1\programfile\explorer.exe` to `C:\programfile\explorer.exe` in visual basic 6?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function QueryDosDevice Lib "kernel32" Alias "QueryDosDeviceA" (ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpTargetPath As String, ByVal ucchMax As Long) As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Debug.Print pvReplaceDevice("\Device\HarddiskVolume1\aaa.txt")
End Sub

Private Function pvReplaceDevice(sPath As String) As String
    Dim sDrive          As String
    Dim sDevice         As String
    Dim lIdx            As Long

    For lIdx = 0 To 25
        sDrive = Chr$(65 + lIdx) & ":"
        sDevice = Space(1000)
        If QueryDosDevice(sDrive, sDevice, Len(sDevice)) <> 0 Then
            sDevice = Left$(sDevice, InStr(sDevice, Chr$(0)) - 1)
'            Debug.Print sDrive; "="; sDevice
            If LCase$(Left$(sPath, Len(sDevice))) = LCase$(sDevice) Then
                pvReplaceDevice = sDrive & Mid$(sPath, Len(sDevice) + 1)
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    pvReplaceDevice = sPath
End Function
```

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you, @user757321, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an efficient use of API functions, create a class - "DiskDevice"

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetLogicalDriveStrings Lib "Kernel32" Alias "GetLogicalDriveStringsW" ( _
    ByVal nBufferLength As Long, _
    ByVal lpBuffer As Long _
) As Long

Private Declare Function QueryDosDevice Lib "Kernel32.dll" Alias "QueryDosDeviceW" ( _
    ByVal lpDeviceName As Long, _
    ByVal lpTargetPath As Long, _
    ByVal ucchMax As Long _
) As Long

Private m_colDrivesKeyedByDevice            As VBA.Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Dim sDriveStrings               As String
    Dim vasDriveStrings             As Variant
    Dim nIndex                      As Long
    Dim sDrive                      As String

    ' Allocate max size buffer [A-Z]:\\\0  and retrieve all drives on the system.
    sDriveStrings = Space$(105)
    GetLogicalDriveStrings 1000, StrPtr(sDriveStrings)

    ' Split over the null chars between each substring.
    vasDriveStrings = Split(sDriveStrings, vbNullChar)

    Set m_colDrivesKeyedByDevice = New VBA.Collection

    ' Iterate through each drive string (escaping later if any item is null string).
    For nIndex = 0 To UBound(vasDriveStrings)
        sDrive = Left$(vasDriveStrings(nIndex), 2) ' Ignore the backslash.
        If Len(sDrive) = 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
        ' Create mapping from Drive => Device
        m_colDrivesKeyedByDevice.Add sDrive, GetDeviceForDrive(sDrive)
    Next nIndex

End Sub

' Retrieve the device string \device\XXXXXX for the drive X:
Private Function GetDeviceForDrive(ByRef the_sDrive As String)

    Const knBufferLen       As Long = 1000
    Dim sBuffer             As String
    Dim nRet                As Long

    sBuffer = Space$(knBufferLen)
    nRet = QueryDosDevice(StrPtr(the_sDrive), StrPtr(sBuffer), knBufferLen)
    GetDeviceForDrive = Left$(sBuffer, nRet - 2) ' Ignore 2 terminating null chars.

End Function

Public Function GetFilePathFromDevicePath(ByRef the_sDevicePath As String) As String

    Dim nPosSecondBackslash As Long
    Dim nPosThirdBackslash As Long
    Dim sDevice         As String
    Dim sDisk           As String

    ' Path is always \Device\<device>\path1\path2\etc. Just get everything before the third backslash.
    nPosSecondBackslash = InStr(2, the_sDevicePath, "\")
    nPosThirdBackslash = InStr(nPosSecondBackslash + 1, the_sDevicePath, "\")

    sDevice = Left(the_sDevicePath, nPosThirdBackslash - 1)
    sDisk = m_colDrivesKeyedByDevice.Item(sDevice)          ' Lookup

    ' Reassemble, this time with disk.
    GetFilePathFromDevicePath = sDisk & Mid$(the_sDevicePath, nPosThirdBackslash)

End Function
```

Now, you use code like:

```
Set m_oDiskDevice = New DiskDevice

...

sMyPath = m_oDiskDevice.GetFilePathFromDevicePath("\Device\HarddiskVolume1\programfile\explorer.exe")
```

That way you don't have to call the API functions multiple times - you just do a collection lookup.